# Can we have a date shortcode?

Tags: feature-request, dates, date-format

Sometimes we enter dates into questions and answers. It recently came up on Skeptics Meta what format we should prefer. Since it seems SE has its own format scheme (possibly varied based on location), a date shortcode would be pretty sweet.

Something like `[date:today]` outputs today's date. Something like `[date:2019-08-19]` outputs August 19th 2019 in whatever SE's preferred format is. Something like `[date:1234]` outputs the date of the post with the id 1234. Etc.

Comment: The relevant Skeptics Meta post: https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4415/11643

Comment: *whatever SE's preferred format is.*  ... it would probably output **1 days ago** ....

Comment: @rene Yes, I guess the "today" portion would be different ...

Comment: AFAIK, SE only has 2 exact date formats: `MMM dd 'yy` (shown by default), or `yyyy-MM-dd` (ISO8601 when hovered). And unless I misunderstood "*possibly varied based on location*", there's no localised date on SE... except on localised SE sites (Portuguese uses `dd/MM/yy`, Spanish uses `dd MMM yy`, Russian uses `dd MM 'yy`, Japanese uses `yy年MM月dd日`) .